# Conjugate of two transitions in isometry group of the plane

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $v_1\cdot v_1 = v_2\cdot v_2$. Show that translation by $v_1$ is conjugate to translation by $v_2$ in the isometry group of the plane.

I think all I need to do is to find a solid motion $\sigma$ of the plane such that $\sigma t_{v_1}\sigma^{-1}=t_{v_2}$. It is clear that a certain reflection will do the work. This is because $rt_vr^{-1}=r_{v'}$, where $v'=r(v)$. In this case, $v'=r(v_1)=v_2$. Since reflection is rigid motion, this is where we require that $v_1$ and $v_2$ have the same length. BTW, I think the reflection axis is simply the $\pi/4$ line through the origin. My question is whether my reasoning is sufficient for this question? Thank you!